# Cannot assign instance name to concurrent workflow in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

In Informatica, I can start a workflow but cannot get it to recognize my instance name in the session log and Workflow Monitor.

The workflow starts but in the session log it displays this:

```
Workflow wf_Tenter image description hereemp started with run id [22350], run instance name [], run type [Concurrent Run with Un[enter image description here][1]ique Instance Name]
```

Instance name is blank.

My command is:

```
pmcmd startworkflow -sv <service> -d <domain> -u <user> -p <password> -f <folder> -rin INST1 -paramfile <full param file path name>  wf_Temp
```

I have edited the workflow and selected the checkbox Configure Current Execution.  Inside Configure Concurrent Execution button, I have created three instances: INST1, INST2, INST3, but without any associated parameter files.  All parameter files are blank.

I understand, I think, that in order to start a workflow with PMCMD I must pass in one of the configured instance names (i.e. INST1, INST2, INST3, etc.)

If I execute the PMCMD command from Putty a second time to see the second instance run, I receive a message that workflow is still running and I have to wait?  Why?  I have checked the Concurrent Workflow box in the workflow.

```
ERROR: Workflow [wf_Temp]: Could not start execution of this workflow because the current run on this Integration Service has not completed yet.
Disconnecting from Integration Service
```

So, I think I'm close, but am missing something.  The workflow runs with the parameter file I pass in PMCMD but the instance name seems to be ignored.

Further.  Do, I have to pre-configure instance names in the Workflow manager?  Is the PMCMD instance and parameter file parameters enough?  It doesn't seem quite so dynamic if Instances have to be pre-defined in the workflows.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

@MacieJG

Here's the screenshots from Putty when I run the command.  You can see the instance name DALLAS is being passed through the PMCMD OK.  No combination ever gets the Instance name.  I did not include the pics of your suggested Test 1, but results were same..  still no instance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try two tests: try running the DALLAS instance mentioned below (-rin DALLAS) with concurent execution set to "Allow concurrent run with same instance name" and then with "Allow concurrent run only with unique instance name" and DALLAS created on the list. Share the results.

Comment: On the putty screen I can see a message saying that wf_Temp with run instance name [DALLAS] and run id [22807] started successfully. So it works, doesn't it?

Comment: I do not see the Instance name DALLAS in the workflow monitor, nor the session log.  But, yes, you 'do' see it in the putty window as the PMCMD command output.  But, from a paste in my original question, it is not in the session log.  Nor, can I run the putty cmd back to back after changing DALLAS to HOUSTON (for example).  I get a message that the flow is running and I must wait.   I have tried countless experiments to get this one feature to work in Informatica.... i 'do not' ever see an Instance name in the Monitor or log....even though docs say it over and over that that's how it works

Comment: So we now the pmcmd syntax is proper and is being read correctly by the command..... why it doesn't get picked up by the actual workflow and include it in the LOG.....Mainly, I want to see the instance name in the Workflow Monitor... that's really what I'm after.

Comment: I'll figure out why -nowait doesn't seem to work either later.... As a java Developer, I love the notion of threads and concurrent workflows.

Comment: @Maciejg, do you have a sample perhaps of your own you could export and send me?  I can see your version of this.  Maybe there's something else I am overlooking....... i sooo appreciate your effort to help.  Maybe you could create a workflow like I have, that just calls a timer for a minute, and see if you can get your version to work?

Comment: @davidson I was facing exactly the same issue and it is resolved by restarting the integration service. We did not restart integration service to fix this issue. But it resolved this issue. When we contacted informatica support for resolution, below KB link is providd by them. https://kb.informatica.com/solution/23/Pages/59/501120.aspx Please find the thread I have opend in Informatica network. https://network.informatica.com/thread/83540 Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my complete test as requested in a comment above. I tried my best to put everything you may need here, but if I missed anything, just let me know. So here goes...

I've created a very simple workflow to run with instance name. It uses a timer to wait and a command tast to write the instance name to a file:

[image: Workflow overview]

The concurrent execution has been set up in the most simple way:

[image: Workflow configuration]

Now, I've prepared the followig batch to run the workflow (just user & password removed):

```
SET "PMCMD=C:\Informatica\9.5.1\clients\PowerCenterClient\CommandLineUtilities\PC\server\bin\pmcmd"
%PMCMD% startworkflow -sv Dev_IS -d Domain_vic-vpc -u ####### -p ####### -f Dev01 -rin GLASGOW wf_Instance_Test
%PMCMD% startworkflow -sv Dev_IS -d Domain_vic-vpc -u ####### -p ####### -f Dev01 -rin FRANKFURT wf_Instance_Test
%PMCMD% startworkflow -sv Dev_IS -d Domain_vic-vpc -u ####### -p ####### -f Dev01 -rin GLASGOW wf_Instance_Test
```

It runs three instances, two of them with same name, just to test it. I run the batch the following way to capture the output:

```
pmStartTestWF.bat > c:\MG\pmStartTestWF.log
```

Once I execute it, here what I see in workflow monitor:

[image: Workflow Monitor]

Just as expected, three instances executed and properly displayed. File output looks fine as well:

[image]

The output of pmcmd can be found [here.](https://pastebin.com/YeMQyGuY) Full definition of my test workflow is available [here.](https://pastebin.com/enz0VZiu)

I really hope this will help you somehow. Feel free to let me know if you'd find anything missing here. Good luck!

Comment: I imported your example.... It works... now I need to fine-tooth-comb my own workflow and narrow down what I'm missing.  I thank you so much.  i will return soon with why mine was not working.

Comment: I decided my flow 'wf_Temp' was corrupted in some way and my changes weren't actually being saved like I thought.  So, I created a brand-new workflow 'wf_Temp2', and it worked first time with instance names.  I feel awful that I didn't think of this earlier.  It all works as advertised.  Your example, though proved to me that it was definitely something on my side here.  The What-IFer in me, said, let's just start with a brand-new flow--something's wrong with the original one.   That was it, I think.  Perfect.

Comment: Glad I could help and you've managed to get this resolved! Still, it will bother me for a while that I don't know what the root cause was :D If you could compare the exported XMLs and figure something out, let me know. I'll start sleeping good sooner :D Cheers!

Comment: Very good idea.  I will do that.  I hate not-knowing exactly what the problem was too.

Comment: Comparing XML's between the two versions were same except for timestamps and the names.  Then, suddenly, my original workflow started showing the instance name out of the blue, after all this time.  wow... I can only suggest on this one there was a gremlin somewhere.  But, I thank you very much for your dedication.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pre-configure instance names in workflow. Passing the instance name in pmcmd along with parameter filename is enough.

Comment: Thank you for that confirmation.  From the original question, do you have an idea on why I am not seeing the instance name in the session logs? And really, I really want to see the instance name in the Monitor when the workflow is running for visuals on what instance is running.

Answer (score 1):

try this: pmcmd startworkflow -sv (service) -d (domain) -u (user) -p (password) -f (folder) -paramfile (full param file path name) -rin INST1 wf_Temp

Comment: Thank you... I have confirmed all my parms are in the correct sequence and format.  Please see my reply on the next message

Answer (score 1):

To be precise: when you configure Concurrent Execution, you can specify if you:

- allow concurrent run with same instance name
- allow concurrent run only with unique instance name

In addition to that you may, but don't have to, indicate which instance should use which parameter file, so it won't be need to mention it while executing. But that's a separate feature.

Now, if you've chosen the first one, you will be able to invoke the WF multiple times with the very same command. If you've chosen the second one and try this, you will get the 'WF is already running' error.

The trouble is that your example seems correct at first glance. As per the log message:

```
Workflow wf_Temp started with run id [22350], run instance name [], run type [Concurrent Run with Unique Instance Name]
```

So you're allowing unique instances only. It seems that the instance name has not been used. First execution does not set the instance name, so similar second execution won't use it either and will get rejected as this is the same instance name (i.e. None).

You may try to change the setting to `Allow concurrent run with same instance name`, this shall allow the secon execution, but does not solve the main issue. For some reason the instance name does not get passed.

Please verify your command against the docs referenced below. Try to match the order perhaps. Please share some more info if it still fails.

Looking at the docs:

pmcmd StartWorkflow
<<-service|-sv> service [<-domain|-d> domain] [<-timeout|-t> timeout]>
<<-user|-u> username|<-uservar|-uv> userEnvVar>
<<-password|-p> password|<-passwordvar|-pv> passwordEnvVar>
[<<-usersecuritydomain|-usd> usersecuritydomain|<-usersecuritydomainvar|-usdv>
userSecuritydomainEnvVar>]
[<-folder|-f> folder]
[<-startfrom> taskInstancePath]
[<-recovery|-norecovery>]
[<-paramfile> paramfile]
[<-localparamfile|-lpf> localparamfile]
[<-osprofile|-o> OSUser]
[-wait|-nowait]
**[<-runinsname|-rin> runInsName]**
workflow

Comment: I have confirmed my options sequence list match the 'docs'.  My example above shows that Infa understands I want "Concurrent Run with Unique Instance Name" and I'm supplying the -rin option.  Workflow Edit for Concurrent Workflow requries at least one instance be created, so I have only the 'RUNINSTANCE1' default that is supplied when you add an instance.  This is my command with certain details masked...pmcmd startworkflow -sv xxx -d xxx -u michael.davidson -p xxx -usd xxx -f Davidson -paramfile /opt/informatica/version_10/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles/dh_parms_DAL.par -rin DALLAS wf_Temp

Comment: you mean that "-rin DALLAS" doesn't start the DALLAS instance? This is odd, it should work exactly this way. This means, we're missing some detail, probably. Can you show some screens of workflow definition? Can you look at the admin console (or request someone's help) to confirm the request has been received correctly? Is the repository / folder correct (just in case you'd apply changes on one env and test on the other)? Sorry to bother you with some obvious questions, but I guess that since everything looks good at first glance, there's got to be some tiny bug.

Comment: I agree I'm probably off somewhere simple.  When you said '...start the DALLAS instance', I just have this one simple workflow.  Nothing in the workflow knows anything about DALLAS.  Could I be missing some reference to DALLAS?  I thought the parms in the PMCMD would be all I need--instance name, and param file.   --Is there supposed to be a configured 'DALLAS instance' in the workflow so pmcmd knows which to start?  My goal is one generic (basically) workflow that is called over and over with a new instance name and its related parameter file.    Am not sure how to attach screenshot.

Comment: Added three pics... whatever else we need, I can add.

Comment: also, all work is in DEV environment, so version mis-match would not be an issue.  All activity in DEV environment.  No worries on questions being a bother... I am grateful for the help.  I think we are so close, but missing something small.